# Ember Data RESTAdapter is not Submitting Requests to the Server when I run Model#find()

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am developing an Ember app.  I am serving the API and the ember app from the same server on localhost.

I am pretty sure my API conforms to Ember specifications (although I'm not sure, because conflicting information is given [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/) and [here](http://jsonapi.org/format/).  The second site is linked to from [this](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/05/03/ember-data-progress-update.html) Ember blog post, and is supposed to be a formalization of Ember's conventions).  My API follows the style of the second link, so requesting `host/api/users/1`, for instance, returns:

```
{
  "users": [{
      "username": "jojo"
      etc..
  }]
}
```

I know my API is working because I can test it with `curl`.  My problem is that Ember data doesn't seem to be making requests.  The Chrome developer tools network tab shows that no request to load the data is being sent when I run `App.User.find()`.  I do however get back this:[image]

Here is the coffeescript code where I define the store:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend
  revision: 13
  url: 'http://localhost:9292/'
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter

DS.RESTAdapter.reopen
  namespace: 'api'
```

And here is where I define the model, controller, and route for 'User':

```
App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    App.User.find()

App.UsersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend()

App.User = DS.Model.extend
  username: DS.attr 'string'
  url: DS.attr 'string'
  projects: DS.hasMany 'App.Project'
  query_instances: DS.hasMany 'App.QueryInstance'
```

Am I missing something important here?  I am new to Ember and client-side development in general-- perhaps there are obvious solutions here but I'm not aware of them. I'd appreciate if anyone could give a few tips on debugging Ember in general.

Comment: Your second link http://jsonapi.org/format/ is a new format that ember-data will eventually conform to. For the current ember-data your API should conform to the specifications at http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/ for the smoothest experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by upgrading to more recent versions of Ember and Ember data.  I think that I was using incompatible versions.  I initially generated my project using the [Yeoman ember generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-ember).  I seriously doubt that this generator would actually give you incompatible versions, so I'm not quite sure what the problem was.  It may have been:

- An issue with my bower cache
- An incorrect statement of the `revision` number in the `DS.Store` declaration, which I may have changed because I was unclear as to whether this needed to be included.  It is not needed in the latest version, but that's not what the Yeoman generator was providing. So I may have deleted it, then added it back with the wrong version number.

In any case, for anyone else having similar problems I advise you to upgrade your versions of Ember and Ember Data and ensure that they are compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Since the framework is very jung there are still not so much tools besides the browser console and a debugging affiniti to debug ember applications, but some stuff exists that can help out with this task.

**1.** Not nearly ready for prime time but very usefull to inspect ember.js app's is the [ember extension for chrome.](https://github.com/tildeio/ember-extension)

**2.** Since this [PR](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2694) it exists the possibility to set the flag `LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION` to get information about what get's generated by ember under the hood. The active generation logging can be simply enabled with:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION: true
});
```

**3.** For debugging only but very usefull is the `__container__`, one can inspect everything ember-data knows about it's models with ease like this:

```
App.__container__.lookup('store:main').recordCache
```

This will give you access to the store's recordCache, e.g. all the loaded records.
To inspect more in detail you can access specific records like this:

```
App.__container__.lookup('store:main').recordCache[7].get('data.attributes')
```

**4.** One more thing might be also usefull is to define/override the global error handler to catch all errors happening inside an ember app:

```
Ember.onerror = function(error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

**5.** There is also the possibility to log records directly in your templates by using the `log` handlebars helper

```
{{log post}}
```

or simply set a debugger breakpoint to inspect further

```
{{debugger}}
```

Hope this information helps you debug successfully your app.

Comment: Thanks for all the great advice!  I'm sure this stuff is going to come in handy.  I am still working on this specific problem though-- do you have any idea what would cause Ember Data to not even make a request?  It tells me in the console that it is using the RESTAdapter, but how would I confirm this.  Is there a command to tell Ember data to make a request other than `find()`?  Thanks.

Comment: @SeanMackesey you could use `findAll()` but not sure though this solves you particularly problem. You could also try to remove for testing your defined relationships, since this is might causing the RestAdapter to not issues any request at all.